# Android Deep Sleep

Tags: standby

I am confused about the utility of *deep sleep* over *complete shut down*. When I am putting my phone to *deep sleep*, I am no longer getting SMSes nor can people call me. I receive the backlog SMSes after *power on*. Why should I use it instead of *complete shut down*?

What keeps running during *deep sleep*? What's the point?

Comment: I would assume "deep sleep" is akin to Windows' "Hibernate".  That is, the state of everything is preserved as is, so whatever was running before is still running when you wake up.

Comment: Faster startup would be the biggest reason to deep sleep as opposed to completely shutting down.

Comment: I've never heard of "deep sleep" when working with Android. Where are you seeing this option?

Comment: What Al Everett said.

Comment: Unlike many phones, no Android phone I know of has a deep sleep state where (usually) nothing but the alarm works.  It's either off or on.  Unless you can provide more info this question can't be answered.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you're talking about airplane mode?  If so, it saves on battery without having to actually turn off your phone by shutting down all the radios.  It's also useful for places that don't allow cell phones (hospitals, airplanes during take off/landing, etc) in that it won't ring, etc.